# ipsec - (encrypt the network traffic) on SDN

Tags: encryption, ipsec, openflow, sdn

OpenFlow protocol (1.0 and 1.1) does not define any mechanism about encrypt network traffic (traffic between switches)..

Is it possible to encrypt network traffic on SDN networks.. (like, run IpSEC on top of SDN switches )

Answer (score 0):

Openflow protocol is defined between switches and the controller(Floodlight, Ryu, ODL etc). Openflow uses TLS encryption and it does not specify anything regarding the communication between the switches. The communication between the switches still has to be handled by the switches themselves. Hence what ever encryption the switches support they can be configured on those ports where encryption is required. Openflow protocol is not related to this

Answer (score -1):

It is not done yet, however a research is being carried out in order to standardize it with NETCONF protocol. Here is the IETF draft:

[IPSec & SDN Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056846/ipsec-encrypt-the-network-traffic-on-sdn)